# RegEx for alternating digits ONCE in a sequence of 6 digits

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have tried the following pattern to check for the occurrence of alternate digits on various positions using `|` and using negative lookaheads:

```
(\d)\d\1(?!(\d)\d\2)\d{3}|\d{2}(\d)\d\3\d|(?!(\d)\d\4)(\d)\d\5
```

**These values are valid:**

`101123`

`121013`

**These are invalid:**

`101101`

`111111`

Comment: What do you mean by "alternate number"?

Comment: Do you need to use regex? If not, you could write a simple function

Comment: Do you mean you need a regex pattern that will match the invalid values? Is a value invalid if the first three digits are the same as the last three digits?

Comment: Looks like you want to avoid matching 6-digit chunks having repeating 2- or 3-digit sequences, right? Are these 6-digit chunks standalone, separate strings that you want to validate, or do they occur in larger text and you extract them? If you validate standalone strings, try `r"^(?!\d*(\d{2,3})\d*\1)\d{6}$"`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/GYdp8q/1).

Comment: Note that the last alternation segment `(?!(\d)\d\4)(\d)\d\5` will never match anything.

Answer (score 0):

[This regex](https://regex101.com/r/5J5HgY/1) might help you to `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` the repeating two and three digits in the first capturing group `()`, and then returns the other desired six digits numbers:

```
(\d{2,3}).*\1(*SKIP)(*F)|([0-9]{6})
```

[image]

The first group captures your undesired numbers using [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/beFCv4/1), which you might be able to do a simple string replace on it and remove these numbers from your inputs:

```
(\d{2,3}).*\1
```

[image]

#### Graph:

This graph shows how it works:

[image]

#### Edit

`(*SKIP)(*F)` is a PCRE command, will not work with Python.

Comment: This is a PCRE regex that will not work with Python `re`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here you go, this will match only if there
is not a sequence of repeated every other digit
within each sequence of 3 digits.

ie.   `D1 d D1 D2 d D2`  fail
or      `D1 d D1 D2 d D2 d D3 d D3` fail

`^(?!(?:(\d)\d\1)+$)\d+$`

https://regex101.com/r/Qn1i3f/1

Readable code

```
 ^ 
 (?!
      (?:
           ( \d )                        # (1)
           \d \1 
      )+
      $ 
 )
 \d+ 
 $
```